# reading a viarble in the document

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This seems like it should be simple i have a menu using Angular that sets a variable "active"

```
<a class="about" href="#" ng-click="active='About Me'">About Me</a>
```

and a Paragraph that will output whatever that active name is

```
<p ng-show="active">You chose <b>{{active}}</b></p>
```

What i can't figure out is now to set up a if check wither if "$active/{{active}} = "about me"" display this block of code so each link will fill the body with different content.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `ng-show="active === 'About Me'"`

Comment: @Ele - wow you're fast! :-) - I was typing that when...

Comment: @RandyCasburn hehe `:)`

Comment: https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/wmBMjd  did you make sure that is enclosed in the tag with controller

Comment: i knew it was simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option
**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<a class="about" href="#" ng-click="active='About Me'">About Me</a>
  <a class="about" href="#" ng-click="active='Home'">Home</a>
<p ng-show="active">You chose <b>{{active}}</b></p>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('test',[]);

app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){

})
```

Make sure that the active scope variable is inside the tag having controller

code sample- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/wmBMjd